# Wurtz reaction for secondary alkyl halide

Tags: organic-chemistry

I have found Wurtz reaction for primary alkyl halide in my textbook. My textbook also says that only primary and secondary alkyl halide shows Wurtz reaction and tertiary alkyl halides doesn't show Wurtz reaction. I tried to write the Wurtz reaction for secondary alkyl halide which is not included in my textbook. I think the product is quaternary alkane. But I faced a problem. It is: Which type of quaternary alkane is produced in this reaction? Vicinal or Geminal? Please help me in this context. [image]

Comment: Just join the two molecules by replacing two halogen atoms with a single bond. It will be the second one.

Comment: That is the Wurtz reaction

Comment: Oh, sorry! I read Chemistry textbook written in Bengali and so I didn't know the spelling of 'Wurtz'. However, I have edited it. Thank you.

Comment: @AdityaRoychowdhury Is this an elimination reaction?

Comment: You can find the mechanism and more [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133486/61578) for Wurtz reaction. It is a coupling reaction, by the way.

Comment: @Md.HasibulHossain It is not an elimination reaction. Please read the answer linked in the comment above. Moreover, it is worth mentioning that while Wurtz reaction is generally radical, it may be ionic as well, sometimes. Maybe, it begun with the o sound in bengali so you got confused with the name.